# RNN coding in python using only numpy libraries

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network

while learning Recurrent Neural Network for NLP i'm able to easily understand the theoretical concept of it, but i'm finding it hard to code it in python without using any libraries from keras or tensorflow.

Any advice on how i can go about coding RNNs for deeper understanding? i've been googling RNNs from scratch but all links are proving to be of no help or i'm just that stupid to understand them :-).

any coding links on RNNs will be of great help.

Thank You

Comment: The question asks largely for opinion-based answers which are generally not meant to be asked on SO. What you could do is look at the source code of typically used libraries such as sklearn to see how the models are implemented there.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with a book on linear algebra and then a book on machine learning or perhaps one on recurrent neural networks or natural language processing, depending on how in depth you want to go.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.